# Rendering a specific entity form field in twig

Tags: symfony, twig

In my form builder, i have something like that :

```
$builder->add('User.username', 'text', array())
...
```

But my problem is that, in twig, I can't render that field using :

```
 {{ form_widget(profile_form.User.username) }}
```

even if the field is rendered if I use the form_rest method:

```
 {{ form_rest(profile_form) }}
```

Please note that I need to prepend the Entity User to the field name, because it is a related Entity.

Any way to render this field ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should use [property_path](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#property-path)

```
$builder->add('user_username', 'text', array('property_path' => 'user.username'))
```